# login in wordpress using gmail account

Tags: plugins, login

I implementing log in in my WordPress website for only company employees. I want user can only log in with company given Gmail Email id and no one else can see the details of website what should i do .I m new on this please help me.

Thank in advance....

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-gmail-login/ U can try uploading this extension..

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this plugin.This plugin allow your visitors to login with social networks such as Twitter, Facebook, Google, Yahoo and more. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-social-login/

Comment: i want to use only gmail id which has been provided by company to employees ....

Comment: Please check the plugin by installing once.you can choose only gmail account option to login.